# How to auto play youtube video on my app?

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube, android-youtube-api

My youtube api working fine it's playing video.
I just want when the open `video.kt` activity player will autoplay the video.

`video.kt`

```
   val youtubefragment: YouTubePlayerSupportFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment)
        as YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
        youtubefragment.initialize(API_KEY,object:YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{
            override fun onInitializationSuccess(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider?, player: YouTubePlayer?, wasRestored: Boolean){
                if(player == null) return
                if (wasRestored)
                    player.play()
                else{
                    player.cueVideo(value)
                    player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT)
                }
            }
            override fun onInitializationFailure(p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?, p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?) {

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to auto play Youtube video, use

```
player.loadVideo(value, 0) //replace 0 with milliseconds for delay in autoplay
```

instead of

```
player.cueVideo(value)
```

please refer the below link for more information

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo(java.lang.String,%20int)